# Page-title Content before block called

Tags: magento2

New to magento, I'm trying to find where is defined the content of one of my page. But I can't find it

I found the action called before I have my page

```
/**
 * Forgot customer account information page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_edit');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }

    $data = $this->session->getCustomerFormData(true);
    $customerId = $this->session->getCustomerId();
    $customerDataObject = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $customerDataObject,
            $data,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface::class
        );
    }
    $this->session->setCustomerData($customerDataObject);
    $this->session->setChangePassword($this->getRequest()->getParam('changepass') == 1);

    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Account Information'));
    return $resultPage;
}
```

I found the block definition

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_account_edit_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Edit Account Information</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" name="customer_edit" template="Magento_Customer::form/edit.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And the edit.phtml basicly has only a form inside.

I understand that logic, but I need to find the information which is right before my block (my page title).

This is the resulting html in console

```
<div class="column main">
    <div class="page-title-wrapper">
        <h1 class="page-title">
            <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper">Modif pwd</span>    </h1>
    </div>
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="r2o2eCfdxErTAM4y">
    <div id="authenticationPopup" data-bind="scope:'authenticationPopup'" style="display: none;">
    </div>

<form class="form form-edit-account"></form>

</div>
```

I want to find where is defined this `Modif pwd`

Thanks